# All of the music file names from SD card can be displayed in TextView, but not in ListView?

Tags: android

I am trying to make a media player. For this I need to show all of the `mp3` files stored in `/sdcard/Music/` folder (and under its subfolders) in a `listview`. But the problem is, I cannot access the files that are stored in the subfolders, it is only showing the names of files which are stored in `Music` folder. But if I try to display the names in a textview, it shows each and every file name, even which exist in the subfolders. Here is my code:

```
public class playlist extends Activity {
TextView tv;
ListView list;
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.playlist);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    Scanner("/sdcard/Music/");

}

private void Scanner(String path) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    {
        try 
        {
                File fl = new File(path);
                File[] listOfFiles = fl.listFiles();

                ArrayList<String> listTest = new ArrayList<String>( );

                for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles)
                 {
                    String s = listOfFile.getName();
                    if(s.endsWith(".mp3"))
                    {
                    //tv.setText( tv.getText()+"\n"+s);
                    listTest.add(s);

                    }


                    /////////////////////////////////
                    File f = new File(path+s+"/");
                    if (f.exists() && f.isDirectory()) {
                    Scanner(path+s+"/");
                    }
                    /////////////////////////////////


                }

                listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(playlist.this, R.layout.simplerow, listTest);
                list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        }
    catch (Exception e) { }
    }
}
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating arraylist in Scanner method.

So when you find a directory again list is created.

Try this below code

```
public class playlist extends Activity {
TextView tv;
ListView list;
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.playlist);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayList<String> listTest = new ArrayList<String>( );

    Scanner("/sdcard/Music/");

    if(listTest.size() != 0){
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (playlist.this,R.layout.simplerow, listTest);
        list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

}

```
private void Scanner(String path) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
{
    try 
    {
            File fl = new File(path);
            File[] listOfFiles = fl.listFiles();              

            for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles)
             {
                String s = listOfFile.getName();
                if(s.endsWith(".mp3"))
                {
                //tv.setText( tv.getText()+"\n"+s);
                listTest.add(s);

                }


                /////////////////////////////////
                File f = new File(path+s+"/");
                if (f.exists() && f.isDirectory()) {
                Scanner(path+s+"/");
                }
                /////////////////////////////////


            }



    }
catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

}

Let me know the result

Comment: It's working @NareshReddy.. Though when I used your code an error was showing on listTest.add(s), i.e. listTest cannot be resolved. Then I declared listTest before onCreate and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `Scanner` (by the way in java by convention the function name should start with lowercase letter) is recursive. It is the good approach to scan file name in subfolder.

But you instantiate the list of file to display in the recursive function, so it is not working as expected.
You should separate the recursive scanning and the instantiation of the list.

```
 private void Scanner(String path, ArrayList<String> listTest) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
{
    try 
    {
            File fl = new File(path);
            File[] listOfFiles = fl.listFiles();

            for (File listOfFile : listOfFiles)
             {
                String s = listOfFile.getName();
                if(s.endsWith(".mp3"))
                {
                //tv.setText( tv.getText()+"\n"+s);
                listTest.add(s);

                }


                /////////////////////////////////
                File f = new File(path+s+"/");
                if (f.exists() && f.isDirectory()) {
                Scanner(path+s+"/", listTest);
                }
                /////////////////////////////////


            }



    }
catch (Exception e) { }

}
```

And then call

```
ArrayList<String> listTest = new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner("/sdcard/music", listTest);
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(playlist.this,  R.layout.simplerow, listTest);
list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: It is displaying the same output.